# How to create a Blur effect in C

Tags: c, cs50

Part of a problem set for a course im doing (CS50) requires us to do apply a blur filter on an image. From a two dimensional array[i][j] we need to find the adjacent pixels to the one we want to blur and take the average RGB values and exchange them for the values in the pixel.

This is the code that I came up with yet it does not work.

I have watched some tutorials and they say to find the relative position of the pixel but i cannot really get my head aroud it.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the code I wrote for now:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    int counter_pixel = 0;
    //I would assume that we would need to tell the computer to free up space for the new imafe with malloc()
    RGBTRIPLE temporary[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // go through every column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temporary[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    // go through every row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // go through every column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //checking if the pixel is inside the image
            red = green = blue = 0;
            if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > height +1 || j > width + 1)
            {
                image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;

                image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;

                image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue = temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue = temporary[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;

                counter_pixel++;

                red = round(((temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + temporary[i][j -1].rgbtRed) / counter_pixel));
                green = round(((temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + temporary[i][j -1].rgbtGreen) / counter_pixel));
                blue = round(((temporary[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + temporary[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + temporary[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + temporary[i][j -1].rgbtBlue) / counter_pixel));
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Given the range of the pair of loops which cross the imge, `if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > height +1 || j > width + 1)` will never be true.

Comment: There is quite a lot of problem with this code. Another thing is you did not reset `counter_pixel` for each pixel.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I changed that part. However it gives me an error of an unused variable red which i do not understand as i have stated the variable and then used later in my code...

Comment: Yes, `red` `green` and `blue` have been calculated but are not used.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Its the hardest out of the 4 filters in the problem set, the others i could do with no problem. Do you know how you would code it? Im just starting my coding journey :/

Comment: There are a *lot* of CS50 "blur" questions on this stack. See if you can find some.

Comment: Thanks man. Great help! first time posting a question and such quick feedback. Greatly appreciated.